# Email intent - All apps associated with this action have been turned off, blocked, or not installed

Tags: android, android-intent

My app is sending an email with an attachment using an Intent:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
Uri emailUri = new FileHelper().getUri(file, context);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, emailUri);
emailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
emailIntent.setType("text/html");
// set other stuff like to and from address
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, message.chooserMessage));
```

A user is reporting that when performing this action, he gets the message "All apps associated with this action have been turned off, blocked, or not installed".  I happen to have the same type of phone and tested with no problems, so it is specific to some kind of configuration on his device.  He says he has three email apps installed (default, GMail, and something called Blue Mail) and all are configured and work properly.

I have looked through everything I can find online about this error and can't find anything applicable to my situation.  Anyone have ideas on what to try other than telling him to factory reset?

Comment: I recommend that you put a MIME type on the `Intent`, identifying the type of content at the `Uri` that you are putting in `EXTRA_STREAM`.

Comment: Yeah I am, it's text/html, see the edit to the question.  @CommonsWare but I may have misunderstood.  This is an email with an attachment, so should the MIME type of the intent match the content of the body of the email, or the attachment?  In this case it would be text/html or I think application/pdf.

Comment: If you are using `EXTRA_STREAM`, the MIME type is the type of the stream. If you are not using `EXTRA_STREAM`, but are using `EXTRA_TEXT`, the MIME type is of the text. Since you are using `EXTRA_STREAM` (and, beyond that, are not using `EXTRA_TEXT`), the MIME type should be for the content identified in `EXTRA_STREAM`.